# Get all columns from postgis table when doing a getFeatureInfo request from mapserver's WMS layer

Tags: wms, mapserver, getfeatureinfo

### some background:

- im using openlayers WMSGetFeatureInfo control to get feature info from a WMS layer.
- the data is in postgis (its a table of points).
- im using mapserver, and you need to define a template file for getfeatureinfo request.

---

if i put in the template file:

> any string

it works. when clicking a feature i get back this string (for any feature of course).

if i put in the template file:

> [date]

it returns the **current** date, (not a column in the table)

if i put in the template file:

> [id]

it returns a number that is not the id column of the feature, though it is different for each feature.

---

how can i request all columns for that feature, as if i would do a "select *" quary ?

thanks allot!

Comment: Would it be OK to use text/plain or GML as outputformat or do you absolutely need text/html?

Comment: gml or plain text are perfect. point is that if i put "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/plain" in the web metadata tag i get Unsupported INFO_FORMAT value (text/html).. only if i put "text/html" it returns something..

Comment: INFO_FORMAT must match the mime type so use text/plain there. The columns to show are selected in layer metadata with "wms_include_items"

Comment: thanks! i had to write infoFormat: "text/plain" and not INFO_FORMAT: 'text/plain' in openlayers and now it returns plain text. but with "wms_include_items" "all" i see only: Layer 'wmstry'
  Feature 8061: 
    Cluster:FeatureCount = '1'
    Cluster:Group = ''
and not all columns. should i still use a template tag??

Comment: or maybe it had something to do with the clustering? even though i am clicking on a single feature

Comment: yes - when i removed the clustering and then clicked a feature i get now all its columns... so thanks allot for that!! i wonder is there a way to keep the clustering? i mean i clicked a single feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes from source data are picked into html templates with syntax

```
[item name=DATE format="$value" escape=none]</td>
```

Use of Mapserver templates is documented in http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/template.html. However, with templating and INFO_FORMAT=text/html it is not possible (without scripting) to automatically select all attributes into GetFeatureInfo response because all the "items" should appear in the template. I have seen that done with some scripting so that templates are created on-the-fly to suit the data.

What is easier is to use either text/plain or application/vnd.ogc.gml as INFO_FORMAT. Then all the attributes which are defined in the mapfile at LAYER level with metadata item "wms_include_items" or "gml_include_items" are written to the GetFeatureInfo response. The desired "SELECT * FROM" output is achieved for the text/plain format with this metadata setting

```
"wms_include_items" "all"
```

Full control over the advertised and allowed info_formats may require the use of metadata items "wms_getfeatureinfo_formatlist" and "wms_feature_info_mime_type" and GetFeatureInfo must be allowed in ""wms_enable_request" list. Read the documentation http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html

Comment: just a comment: this works if the layer is not clustered and the parameter in openlayers is called infoFormat. thanks allot!

Comment: Clusters are newcomers for WMS and others have had problems with those too, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98536/geoserver-point-stacker-does-identify-work-on-non-clustered-points. When user hits the cluster symbol on a map the server should compute in reverse order from what data the cluster was built which may not be simple.